# SharedPreferences ListPreference NullPointerException

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to set up a list of frequencies in my preferences xml but I keep getting this error. I have attached all the related files too. I believe that I set up the values correctly but I can't find where my error currently is. Also, when I use the SharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue) what value is returned? The ENTRY or the ENTRYVALUE?

My Error:

```
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.preference.ListPreference.findIndexOfValue(ListPreference.java:215)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.preference.ListPreference.getValueIndex(ListPreference.java:224)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.preference.ListPreference.getEntry(ListPreference.java:202)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.preference.ListPreference.getSummary(ListPreference.java:148)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.preference.Preference.onBindView(Preference.java:515)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.preference.Preference.getView(Preference.java:453)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.getView(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:222)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2461)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1628)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2296)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4603)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4603)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4603)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4603)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14063)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4603)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1994)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1815)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4518)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
08-20 00:14:25.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

xml layout:

```
<ListPreference 
        android:key="frequency_key"
        android:title="Sample Rate"
        android:defaultValue="8000"
        android:entries="@array/freq_titles"
        android:entryValues="@array/freq_values"
        />
```

xml array:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string-array name="freq_titles">
    <item name="8000">8k Hz</item>
    <item name="16000">16k Hz</item>
    <item name="22050">22.05k Hz</item>
    <item name="44100">44.1k Hz</item>
    <item name="48000">48k Hz</item>
</string-array>

<array name="freq_values">
    <item name="8000">8000</item>
    <item name="16000">16000</item>
    <item name="22050">22050</item>
    <item name="44100">44100</item>
    <item name="48000">48000</item>
</array>

</resources>
```

UPDATE: It's weird even when I do a getAll() from the default shared preferences it shows me that "frequency_key=8k Hz". So it's initialized.

More code from my preference class:

```
public class Settings_ActivityAH extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private Preference myAccountName;
private Preference myGoogleUsername;
private Preference myGooglePassword;
private static Context context;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    context = getActivity();

    if (context == null){
        Log.e("error","context is null");
    }


    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    myAccountName = (Preference) findPreference("account_name_title_key");
    myGoogleUsername = (Preference) findPreference("googleusername_key");
    myGooglePassword = (Preference) findPreference("googlepassword_key");
    myAccountName.setSummary(prefs.getString("account_name_title_key", "none"));
    myGoogleUsername.setTitle("username: "+prefs.getString("googleusername_key", "none"));
    myGooglePassword.setTitle("password: "+prefs.getString("googlepassword_key", "none"));
    Log.e("Check prefs",prefs.getAll().toString());
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    Log.e("in onSharedPref","yea");
    Preference preference = findPreference(key);

    if (preference.getClass() == EditTextPreference.class){
        Log.e("in editText Pref", "yeah");

        if( key.equals("account_name_title_key")){
            myAccountName.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString("account_name_key","none"));
            Log.e("accountname prefs",sharedPreferences.getString("account_name_key","none"));
    }
        if( key.equals("account_name_key")){
            myAccountName.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString("account_name_key","none"));
            Log.e("accountname prefs",sharedPreferences.getString("account_name_key","none"));
    }

    else if (preference.getClass() == PreferenceCategory.class){
        Log.e("in category Pref", "yeah");

        if (key.equals("googleusername_key")){
            myGoogleUsername.setTitle("Username: "+sharedPreferences.getString(key, "none"));
            Log.e("googleusername prefs",sharedPreferences.getString(key, "none"));

        }
        else if( key.equals("googlepassword_key")){
            myGooglePassword.setTitle("Password: "+sharedPreferences.getString(key, "none"));
            Log.e("googlepassword prefs",sharedPreferences.getString(key, "none"));

        }
    }

}
else{
    Log.e("insufficient key called","onSharedPreferenceChanged AH");
}

}
```

}

Comment: Would you post other parts of your code. How did you implement it in java classes?

Comment: Its not in my java classes anywhere except when I need to Get the value that is currently selected but that is not when I am getting the nullpointer exception. I'm getting the error when I go to my Preference menu.

Comment: With regards when you do preferences.getString("key", defValue), it gets the value of the string with that key. If there is no string present, it uses the default value. It is just there incase you call that and there is no string present, so it has something to default to.

Comment: yes, I understand why the defaultValue is there and that it will return the value paired with the key, but my side-bar question is more about **what** the **value is**. Is the value from the EntryValue or just the entry... So what value are you returning from a Preference List when you do these GET functions? This could perhaps the root of my problem. Thanks @Insanity

Comment: It looks like ENTRY is just the name the values are stored under, but ENTRY VALUES are actual values stored. I think.

Comment: So it looks like ENTRIES is actually the key. Possibly, I haven't used this implementation before.

Comment: Try cleaning your project or deleting R.java in your gen directory. I've had this kind of error before because the R class wasn't rebuilt after I did some resource refactoring. This results in Android looking up the wrong resource IDs. And have you added any 9-patches to your resources recently? If those are not perfectly formatted (no pixels that aren't pure black, pure white, or pure transparent in the border) your R file can fail to get updated.

Comment: @TenFour04 sorry mate the clean didn't work and I haven't used 9-patch, but thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @Insanity yeah I understand that but I want to know if I use the getString on this preference if it returns the Entry Name or the Entry Value... Maybe you can call getString or getInt and one will return you the name and one the value? I don't know... That is my question.

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure. What you can do is try out what you said, then log the result. That should tell you.

Comment: If it's literally saying "frequency_key=8k Hz", then it seems that somehow freq_titles and freq_values are getting swapped, because it should say "frequency_key=8000", right?

Comment: For some reason when I changed my freq_values to a <string-array> it works... I still don't understand why, but I can look into it more.

Comment: Also now that's it working I can see that the GetString method is return the ENTRY VALUE that is currently selected

Answer (score 8):

It seems that Android will only accept `string-array`'s as an argument to the `ListPreference` XML attribute `android:entryValues`. This is consistent with the fact that all XML attributes take only arguments with one specific, predetermined type (i.e. int, bool, string, etc.) See the following question: [ListPreference: use string-array as Entry and integer-array as Entry Values doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346916/listpreference-use-string-array-as-entry-and-integer-array-as-entry-values-does)

About your side question, `getString()` will return the element of the `android:entryValues` array corresponding to the clicked entry. The `android:entries` array is used only as a series of display strings for the user, and has no other impact in code, while the values in `android:entryValues` are used for persistent storage within your app.