# ListPreference throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I have a ListPreference:

```
    <ListPreference
        android:entries="@array/frequencies"
        android:entryValues="@array/frequencies_values"
        android:key="pref_key_frequencies"
        android:summary="@string/frequency_pref_summary"
        android:title="@string/frequency_pref_title" />
```

@array/frequencies:

```
<string-array name="frequencies">
    <item>5 minutes</item>
    <item>10 minutes</item>
    <item>15 minutes</item>
    <item>20 minutes</item>
    <item>30 minutes</item>
    <item>60 minutes</item>
</string-array>
```

@array/frequencies_values

```
<integer-array name="frequencies_values">
    <item>300</item>
    <item>600</item>
    <item>900</item>
    <item>1200</item>
    <item>1800</item>
    <item>3600</item>
</integer-array>
```

The elements in the dialog are displayed correctly. However, if I try `frequencyListPreference.setValueIndex(0);` I get a NullPointerException.
Even if I do nothing in my code, if I click on one of the elements of the list, I get:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference
```

If I check the value of one of the elements of the array `frequencyListPreference.getEntryValues()` is always null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where did you create frequencyListPreference object?

Comment: on my Fragment, with frequencyListPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("pref_key_frequencies");

Comment: ok I recently used ListPreference 
some checks:
1)did you do this in onCreate addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
2)and in activity did you do this getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferencesFragment())
        .commit();

Comment: I have 4 others preferences that work just fine

Comment: Then I dont know whats wrong with your code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To my knowledge, Android will only accept String arrays instead of an Integers.

Change

```
<integer-array name="frequencies_values">
    <item>300</item>
    <item>600</item>
    <item>900</item>
    <item>1200</item>
    <item>1800</item>
    <item>3600</item>
</integer-array>
```

To

```
<string-array name="frequencies_values">
    <item>300</item>
    <item>600</item>
    <item>900</item>
    <item>1200</item>
    <item>1800</item>
    <item>3600</item>
</string-array>
```

In your code where you read from the Preference, use Integer.parseInt() to convert the value to a usable integer.

See the follow for more detail: [ListPreference: use string-array as Entry and integer-array as Entry Values doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346916/listpreference-use-string-array-as-entry-and-integer-array-as-entry-values-does)