# ListPreference Storing Values as Strings Not Ints

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm having some trouble understanding how I can save the entry values of a `ListPreference` as integers. As of now, I have defined my `ListPreference` as follows:

```
    <ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="@string/list_preference_sorting_options_default_value"
    android:title="@string/list_preference_sorting_options_title"
    android:key="@string/list_preference_sorting_options_key"
    android:entries="@array/list_preference_sorting_options_entries"
    android:entryValues="@array/list_preference_sorting_options_entry_values"/>
```

...where the `entries` and `entryValues` attributes are defined in the following arrays:

```
<array name="list_preference_sorting_options_entries">
    <item>@string/list_preference_sorting_options_entry_popularity</item>
    <item>@string/list_preference_sorting_options_entry_top_rated</item>
</array>

<array name="list_preference_sorting_options_entry_values">
    <item>@string/list_preference_sorting_options_entry_value_popularity</item>
    <item>@string/list_preference_sorting_options_entry_value_top_rated</item>
</array>
```

I understand that I am using String values within the `list_preference_sorting_options_entry_values` array. However, if I were to define my array in a different way, such as:

```
<array name="list_preference_sorting_options_entry_values">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
</array>
```

...then within my app, if I try accessing the settings activity, my app crashes.

Furthermore, if I try to read my entry values as ints from `SharedPreferences` (even though they're stored as Strings) as follows:

```
int methodFlag = preferences.getInt(getString(R.string.list_preference_sorting_options_key), 0);
```

...then I receive a Java error that I can't cast a String into an int. In order to properly obtain the entry value as an int, I need to use the `getString()` method and then parse it into an int:

```
    String preferenceMethodFlagString = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.list_preference_sorting_options_key),getString(R.string.list_preference_sorting_options_default_value));

    int preferenceMethodFlag = Integer.parseInt(preferenceMethodFlagString);
```

Is there a way for me to directly store integer values through the arrays.xml? If I use this implementation (with the arrays.xml), will I always have to parse the String into an int?

I've seen other SO questions where if the `SharedPreferences.Editor` is used, integer values will be stored into the `ListPreference`'s entry values. Is this the only means to store integer values?

Comment: Haven't received a response on this yet. Would anyone happen to have any input on this?

Comment: What happens if you put your entry-values in an integer-array instead of an array?

Comment: Oh, you can't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346916/listpreference-use-string-array-as-entry-and-integer-array-as-entry-values-does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListPreference has been designed such that it can only hold string values.

Member variables of ListPreference are as follows

```
private CharSequence[] mEntries;
private CharSequence[] mEntryValues;
private String mValue;
private String mSummary;
```

Further, values are read retrieved as

```
mEntries = a.getTextArray(com.android.internal.R.styleable.ListPreference_entries);
mEntryValues = a.getTextArray(com.android.internal.R.styleable.ListPreference_entryValues);
```

getTextArray() looks for string-arrays resource ids only.

**Hence, entries and entryValues should always be string resource.**

If you want to use int values,

```
<string-array name="entries_list_preference">
    <item>0</item> <!-- This does not make it int, it will be stored as string only -->
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="entryvalues_list_preference">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
```

When you are reading its value, parse it as integer.

```
ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference ("list_preference");
String value = listPreference.getValue();
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(value))
    performAction(Integer.parseInt(listPreference.getValue()));
```

Now you can write performAction(int type) method as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. Android just uses String arrays for both entries and entry values. But you can easily convert a String to an int using the `Integer.parseInt()` method. Hope this helps.